# Unicast Frame using Janus channel

Tags: janus, unetstack

I want to send a Janus frame to specific node not a broadcast message in a 4-node network, how to do that? and how to calculate the transfer time to that node?

Answer (score 2):

The JANUS spec doesn't define node addressing, and so the standard JANUS frame isn't able to support `to` and `from` fields. You'd need to put in this information at an application level in the cargo (`data`) or the `appData` field, and use it at the receiving end.

Comment: Ok thank you, and how to calculate the transfer time between two nodes?

Comment: You should see the `rxTime` and `txTime` fields populated in the `RxJanusFrameNtf` and the `TxFrameNtf`. If you've synchronization available (via previous ranging), you can use these to compute transfer time. Alternatively, you'll need to send frames to-and-fro for 2-way time delay measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `txJanusFrameReq`, you can use the `to` field to specify the destination node address, just like you would do with `txFrameReq`. (E.g. `TxFrameReq(to: host('B'))`)

Comment: I don't think `TxJanusFrameReq` has a field called `to`. https://unetstack.net/javadoc/3.0/org/arl/unet/phy/TxJanusFrameReq.html

Comment: Yes, to field is not working with Janus Frame